# SQL join, getting multiple columns with same name

Tags: sql, join

I have one table with a column `ID` and `SERVICE_TYPE_TEXT`, and another table with columns

```
ID, SERVICE_TYPE ...
```

and lots of other columns.

The `SERVICE_TYPE` in the second table contains the `ID` from the first table. I want to query so I can get the `SERVICE_TYPE_TEXT` from the first table that matches the `ID` given in the second table.

I've tried to join, and setting different names on `ID` with `AS`, but always at the end of the query result I get the original ID from the first table with column name `ID`, as well as the name I defined in the AS.

Any suggestions on how I can get the ID from the first table to stay away ? :)

Comment: Please post your select statement in the question, may be the part where you are selecting the column names

Comment: posting the actual query with sample table structure would definitly help here.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `*` that is almost certainly somewhere in your `SELECT` clause (of course, this would be easier to diagnose if we could *see* your query)

Answer (score 21):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT a.ID AS ServiceID,
       a.Service_Type_Text,
       b.ID AS table2ID,
       b.Service_Type
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.Service_Type
```

Comment: what do you want for `table2`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I personally didn't know you could assign columns like that.

Answer (score 14):

Set your query so that it returns all data from the second table but only the required field (column) from the first.
Something like this:

```
SELECT TAB1.SERVICE_TYPE_TEXT, TAB2.*
FROM TAB1
INNER JOIN
TAB2
ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.SERVICE_TYPE
```

Answer (score 6):

TRY

```
 SELECT a.ID AS ServiceID,
       a.Service_Type_Text,
       b.ID AS table2ID,
       b.Service_Type
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN table2 b
           ON a.ID = b.Service_Type AND b.ID='YOUR_ID';
```