# Azure CosmosDB SQL query on nested Array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have a below document structure.

```
{
"id":"GUID",
    "customer": {
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "type": "MOBILE",
                    "status": "CONFIRMED",
                    "value": "xxxx"
                },
                {
                    "type": "EMAIL",
                    "status": "CONFIRMED",
                    "value": "aaaa"
                }
            ],
            "addresses": [
                {

                    "country": "xxx"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

and need to search for customer->contacts where value="aaaa".
 I tried with below options

```
1)  SELECT c.id FROM c
    join customer in c.customer
    join contacts in c.customer.contacts
    where contacts.value = "aaaa"

2) SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE c.customer.contacts[0].value= "aaaa"
```

Getting Syntax error 400 bad request Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your issue is that `value` cannot be searched as easily as other properties. Here are possible solutions:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
join contacts in c.customer.contacts where contacts["value"] = "aaaa"

SELECT c.id FROM c WHERE c.customer.contacts[1]["value"] = "aaaa"
```

[Document DB SQL Api - unable to query json property with name 'value' and its value is integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794971/document-db-sql-api-unable-to-query-json-property-with-name-value-and-its-va)

Comment: Thanks @AlexAIT, your query worked as charm. I was not aware of limitation, JSON property name  - 'value'.